# Convert a string with 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' format to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format

I recognize there has been many questions posted about converting strings to `datetime` already but I haven't found anything for converting a string like `20120225143620` which includes seconds.

I was trying to perform a clean conversion without substring-ing each segment out and concatenating with `/` and `:`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `STUFF()` method to insert characters into your string to format it in to a value SQL Server will be able to understand:

```
DECLARE @datestring NVARCHAR(20) = '20120225143620'

-- desired format: '20120225 14:36:20'
SET @datestring = STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@datestring,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @datestring) AS FormattedDate
```

**Output:**

```
FormattedDate
=======================
2012-02-25 14:36:20.000
```

This approach will work if your string is always the same length and format, and it works from the end of the string to the start to produce a value in this format: `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS`

For this, you don't need to separate the date portion in anyway, as SQL Server will be able to understand it as it's formatted.

**Related Reading:**

[STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

> The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.
>
> STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )

Comment: If ***datestring*** is _GMT + 2_ and I need ***FormattedDate*** like _GMT + 0_ ?

Comment: `YYYYMMDD HH:MM` ***desired format: '20120225 14:36'***
`SET @datestring = STUFF(STUFF(@datestring,9,0,' '),12,0,':')`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @datestring NVARCHAR(20) = '20220822190000330';
DECLARE @dateint BIGINT = CONVERT(BIGINT,@datestring);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,FORMAT(@dateint, '####-##-## ##:##:##:###')) AS FormatDate;
```

**Output**

```
FormatDate
-----------------------
2022-08-22 19:00:00.330
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. The answer could use some explanation though. In particular, this answer is designed to work with a 17-digit date/time string with 3 digits of fraction, instead of the 14 digits from the original post. The advantage here is that the expression could easily be adapted to several source value lengths. I suggest that you update your answer to include both cases.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff')
```

Please run the below sql command for unique key generation with timestamp
[image: Please run the below sql command for unique key generation with timestamp]

Comment: This does not convert a string to a datetime