# How to grab a value from a previous row based off of assignment in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company wants to capture how much time passes between that last scan of a previous assignment and the first scan of a new assignment.

To view the scan times I can use this code:

```
SELECT
    Assignment, 
    Scan_Times 
FROM
    WORK_SUMMARY AS S
JOIN 
    WORK_DETAILS AS D ON S.WORKSUMMARYINTID = D.WORKSUMMARYINTID
ORDER BY 
    Assignment
```

The query returns something like this:

[image: strong text]

So in this example I need to reference the previous assignment 'S4970312205338' and the last scan time '2020-03-13 00:08:01' and then measure the time between that and the first scan of the next assignment. obviously the data isn't ordered correctly so in my matrix the next scan time is before the previous.

Also can anyone help me format the `scan_time` to show as a time like '2020-03-13 00:08:01' instead of '20200313000801' that would be super helpful as well.

Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678191/convert-a-string-with-yyyymmddhhmmss-format-to-datetime

Comment: Edit the question add sample data & desired result..

Comment: add SQL Server version as the answer will depend on that. i.e. @DhruvJoshi answer below uses `lag` which is not available pre-2012 I believe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe query like below may help, but you should definitely improve your question and provide more data (input and desired output)

```
; with datecorrectedset as 
(
    Select 
    Assignment, 
    Scantime=CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(cast(Scan_Times as nvarchar(20)),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ') as datetime)
From WORK_SUMMARY AS S
    JOIN WORK_DETAILS AS D
        ON S.WORKSUMMARYINTID = D.WORKSUMMARYINTID
)

; with lastdataset as
(
    select 
        Assignment,
        Scantime,
        lastAssignment  =   case when assignment <> lag(Assignment) over( order by Scantime asc) then 1 else 0 end,
        lastScantime    =   lag(Scantime) over( order by Scantime asc)
    from datecorrectedset
)

    select 
        Assignment,
        Scantime,
        Timesincelastassignment= datediff(s,lastScantime,Scantime)
    from lastdataset
    where lastAssignment=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @DhruvJoshi answer above, if pre-2012, you can use OUTER APPLY:

```
;WITH formatted AS
(
Select 
    Assignment, 
    Scantime=CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(cast(Scan_Times as nvarchar(20)),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ') as datetime)
From WORK_SUMMARY AS S
    JOIN WORK_DETAILS AS D
        ON S.WORKSUMMARYINTID = D.WORKSUMMARYINTID
)
Select 
    Assignment, 
    Scan_Times,
    PreviousAssignment = prev.Assignment,
    PreviousScantime = prev.Scantime
From Formatted f1
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 f2.Scantime,f2.Assignment 
            FROM Formatted f2 
            WHERE f2.Scantime < f1.Scantime
            ORDER BY f2.Scantime DESC
            ) prev
ORDER BY Assignment
```