# Calculate time difference between 2 columns which are in VARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is:

```
create table Test_Bench
(
    id int,
    start_time varchar(20),
    stop_time varchar(20)
)
```

My data set is:

```
insert into Test_Bench
values (1, '20200520070000', '20200520153000');
```

I want to calculate the difference between my stop_time and start_time in minutes however as the columns are in `varchar` format I am running into error while converting the varchar to int.

I tried converting the varchar to int, bigint, datetime, timestamp but none of them are working
The table is already existing and has been created without following the proper data types of date and time.
Now as per my analysis I am trying to pull out the Date and time from this and then calculate the difference between the times extracted.
My expected output will be

> Difference (2020-05-2020 15:30:00 - 2020-05-2020 07:00:00) = 510 minutes

Comment: So what is the expected results? WHy are you storing numerical data as a `varchar`? In fact, why are you storing date and time data as a numerical value in a `varchar`? There are date and time data types for a reason.

Comment: This will be **so much better** if you can convert the columns to datetime values. You already need to do this for every row in the table every time you run the query in order to use the date functions. Using datetime columns will save that work. Additionally, datetime columns will let you have proper indexes. There's enough of a difference I'd actually call the current schema **broken**.

Comment: @Larnu - I have updated the question with the answers you are looking for

Comment: In newer versions of Sql Server, you can use `TRY_CONVERT()` to safely get datetime values.

Comment: @surya I can't see where you tell us why you aren't using a Date and Time data type?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CAST or CONVERT to Convert varchar to int. 
Select (CAST(start_time as int) - CAST(stop_time as int)) from test_bench

Please try this.

Comment: Could you please give a sample of `SELECT CAST(...)` or `SELECT COVERT(...)` for string like `'20200520070000'`, which would make it `datetime`?  ;)    The `CAST` does not allow custom formats at all and `CONVERT` has limited number of custom formats.

Comment: Do u want to convert it to a date time and check datediff?

Answer (score 0):

A little `STUFF()` and a `TRY_CONVERT()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] varchar(50),[starttime] varchar(50),[endtime] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,20200520070000,20200520153000)

Select *
      ,Minutes = DateDiff(MINUTE
                         ,try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(starttime,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
                         ,try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(endtime  ,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
                         )
 from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
id  starttime       endtime         Minutes
1   20200520070000  20200520153000  510
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678191/convert-a-string-with-yyyymmddhhmmss-format-to-datetime). For your specific schema, try something like this:

```
SELECT id,
DATEDIFF(
  mi,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(start_time,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')),
    CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(stop_time,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
) AS DiffInMins
FROM Test_Bench
```

It would be better if you could convert the dates going into the table, or abstract the conversion into a UDF, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your design, and then this is trivial. There are date and time data types, and you should be using them to store date and time values. Then you just need `DATEDIFF`:

```
create table Test_Bench
(
    id int,
    start_time datetime2(0),
    stop_time datetime2(0)
)

insert into Test_Bench
values (1, '2020-05-20T07:00:00', '2020-05-20T15:30:00');
GO

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time,stop_time)
FROM dbo.Test_Bench;
```